# Reading using DeflateStream doesn't match expected size

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, deflatestream

I'm writing a set of discrete binary data to a stream and then to disk. I'm using a buffered file stream to reduce the disk usage.

```
BinaryWriter -> DeflateStream -> FileStream (buffered)
```

The data set consists of a header part (with some info) and some raw data, compressed;

```
1. Signature, 1 byte.
2. Timestamp, 8 bytes.
3. Size of data uncompressed, 8 bytes
4. Data (compressed, using DeflateStream), X bytes
```

The issue is that when reading the data, doing the inverse operation, the position on the stream doesn't match the expected value.

```
1. Read signature, 1 byte.
2. Read timestamp, 8 bytes (long).
3. Read data size, 8 bytes (long).
4. Read compressed data, using DeflateStream, (above value) bytes.
```

This of course breaks reading of all the other items.
For a data of size 240_000, reading it results in reading more than that.
Since I'm writing the data size right before the raw data, the operation to read the size back is working.

The issue is with the `DeflateStream` or maybe how I'm using it.

### Writer

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 200 * 1_048_576);
var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);

var item = new Item
{
    Signature = (byte)1,
    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks,
    Data = new byte[] { .... }
}

binaryWriter.Write(item.Signature); //1 byte.
binaryWriter.Write(item.TimeStamp); //8 bytes.
binaryWriter.Write(item.Data.LongLength); //8 bytes.

//Reported position: 17 (1 + 8 + 8)
//Data Length: 240_000

using (var compressStream = new DeflateStream(fileStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
{
    compressStream.Write(item.Data);
    compressStream.Flush();
}

//Reported position: 8099 (1 + 8 + 8 + [compressed length])

// Repeats until all items are in cache.
```

### Reader

```
await using var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
using var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);

var items = new List<Item>();

while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
{
    var item = new Item
    {
        StreamPosition = fileStream.Position
    };

    fileStream.Position += 1; //Skip signature.

    item.TimeStampInTicks = binaryReader.ReadInt64(); //
    item.DataLength = binaryReader.ReadInt64(); //, 240_000

    //Reported position: 17 (1 + 8 + 8) //

    await using (var compressStream = new DeflateStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
    using (var compressBinaryReader = new BinaryReader(compressStream))
    {
        compressBinaryReader.ReadBytes((int)item.DataLength);
        //compressStream.ReadBytes((int)item.DataLength);
        //Same results without reader.
    }

    //Reported position: 8306 //
    //Expected position: 8099

    items.Add(item);
}
```

---

### Working Code

I have to store the compressed size as well, and then reposition the stream manually, since the `DeflateStream` overshoots.

### Writer

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 200 * 1_048_576);
var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);

var item = new Item
{
    Signature = (byte)1,
    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks,
    Data = new byte[] { .... }
}

binaryWriter.Write(item.Signature); //1 byte.
binaryWriter.Write(item.TimeStamp); //8 bytes.
binaryWriter.Write(item.Data.LongLength); //8 bytes, uncompressed length.

var start = fileStream.Position;
binaryWriter.Write(0L); //8 bytes, compressed length.

using (var compressStream = new DeflateStream(fileStream, UserSettings.All.CaptureCompression, true))
{
    compressStream.Write(item.Data);
    compressStream.Flush();
}

var end = fileStream.Position;
var compressedLength = end - start - 8; //8 as the position was obtained before the size was written.

fileStream.Position = start;
binaryWriter.Write(compressedLength); //8 bytes, compressed length.
fileStream.Position = end;
```

### Reader

```
await using var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
using var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);

var items = new List<Item>();

while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
{
    var item = new Item
    {
        StreamPosition = fileStream.Position
    };

    fileStream.Position += 1; //Skip signature.

    item.TimeStampInTicks = binaryReader.ReadInt64();
    item.DataLength = binaryReader.ReadInt64();
    var compressedLength = binaryReader.ReadInt64();
    var currentPosition = fileStream.Position;
    
    await using (var compressStream = new DeflateStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
    {
        compressStream.ReadBytes((int)item.DataLength);
    }

    fileStream.Position = currentPosition + compressedLength;

    items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `item.DataLength` the size of uncompressed data? Why don't you store what you're referring to as `[compressed length]` in *Reported position: 8099 (1 + 8 + 8 + [compressed length])*?

Comment: Yes, `DataLength` is the size of uncompressed data. Isn't that what stream uses when reading? If I had to store the compressed size, I would have to store to a `MemoryStream` and then copy to my file stream, so that I would have the length before the data.

Comment: @Evk Reading using the compressed length (8_082 instead of 240_000) also overshoots, goes to the same position (8_306). Weird.

Comment: Specify from what Stream you're reading the *reported position* both when reading and writing -- If you don't store the CRC of the data you're deflating, at least store both the uncompressed and compressed length

Comment: @Jimi From the `FileStream`.

Comment: I was wrong about the compressed\decompressed size in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `DeflateStream` has internal buffer on its own. When you read data from `DeflateStream` - it reads data from underlying stream (in this case from your `fileStream`). It reads them to its own internal buffer, but it doesn't know beforehand how much bytes it should read (so where exactly data ends), and as such and it always tries to read the amount of bytes equal to that buffer length. This means that if your stream contains other bytes AFTER compressed data - it's perfectly fine for `DeflateStream` to overread past the compressed data while trying to fill its internal buffer on the last read. It will not make any use of those bytes, but it will read them and that will advance position on your `FileStream` past the compressed data.

So overread does not indicate any bug in the deflate procedure, however you have to fix the position manually. And for that you need to know the size of compressed data.

Side note - better not use `BinaryReader` to read the data in this case - use `DeflateStream.Read` (don't forget to check the return value of this method, indicating how much bytes were actually read).

Comment: Thanks! Storing both the compressed and uncompressed size and then using it accordingly works. I'm going to update the question with the details.